# Convert multiple JSON strings to different objects with one method

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using the [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) Framework and I'm trying to convert multiple Json strings to different objects using only one method to achieve it.

To create the objects to store the Json data I'm using this [website](http://json2csharp.com/).

So far, I've managed to have one method to convert for one object (in this case `RootObject`) with the code bellow:

```
public class WebService
{
    protected string jsonstring;

    // Other code

    // Method
    public RootObject stringToObject(){
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(this.jsonstring);
    }
}

// Object
public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

// Usage
WebService ws = new WebService ("http://example.com/json_string.json");
RootObject data = ws.stringToObject ();
```

The thing is that I have two more objects that I need to convert a Json string into:

```
public class RootObject2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string menu_id { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject3
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string menu_id { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
    public string active { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried to change the method return type to a generic type but it didn't work:

```
public object stringToObject(){
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(this.jsonstring);
}
```

How can I have the method return type dynamic so I can do something like this:

```
WebService ws = new WebService ("http://example.com/json_string.json");
RootObject data = ws.stringToObject ();

WebService ws2 = new WebService ("http://example.com/json_string2.json");
RootObject2 data2 = ws2.stringToObject ();

WebService ws3 = new WebService ("http://example.com/json_string3.json");
RootObject3 data3 = ws3.stringToObject ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make your `WebService` be [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)?

```
public class WebService<T>
{
    protected string jsonstring;

    // Other code

    // Method
    public T stringToObject(){
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(this.jsonstring);
    }
}
```

Then do

```
var ws = new WebService<RootObject>("http://example.com/json_string.json");
var data = ws.stringToObject ();
```

Or if you prefer, you can just make `stringToObject` be generic:

```
public class WebService
{
    protected string jsonstring;

    // Other code

    // Method
    public T stringToObject<T>(){
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(this.jsonstring);
    }
}
```

And do:

```
var data = ws.stringToObject<RootObject>();
```